# (.tif) file format can't open in chrome

Tags: html, image, google-chrome

Could you tell me what kind of files which is support by chrome ?
I have some .tif file format to show inside my webpage.But that file or image could not appear in my web.

is there any advice for me? any advance would be appreciate.
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia's [browser comparison page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) has a good overview of supported image formats.

Generally speaking, TIF is not a format you should use in a web context. Consider converting the images to PNG or JPG instead.

Comment: this is solve my problem.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which OS you use but at least on Mac OS X Quicktime is used to display, among other formats, TIFF in Chrome. In other words, everything supported by Quicktime should be supported by Chrome.